# Data joins with d3.stack.layout()

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've created a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/yTQbfyug9XV14rMdLThA?p=catalogue) to demonstrate my problem.

The issue is that my .enter(),update(),exit() method is not working for my d3.chart.layout() visualization.

Instead, I get the classic "double post" problem. My keys are the same, however.

What I want to happen is for my d3 steam graph to update its data (such that the y values all go to 0, and the chart disappears). My data binding is coded normally:

```
var steam = svg.selectAll(".layer")
    .data(layers, function(d){console.log(d); return d.key})

steam.enter().append("path")

steam.style("fill", function(d, i) { return z(i); }).style("opacity","0").transition().duration(400)
    .style("opacity","1")
    .attr("class", "layer")
    .attr("d", function(d) { return area(d.values); })

steam.exit().transition().duration(500).remove()
```

What is happening/any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got it to work, though I'm still confused as to why it works this way. I needed to move the svg adding out of the update function and into the namespace (that was obvious).

But the update became this, with a transition() method. Can anyone help me understand where I went wrong?

```
  test = svg.selectAll("path").data(layers, function(d){return d.key})

      test.enter().append("path")

      test.style("opacity",1).style("fill", function(d, i) { return z(i); })
        .attr("class", "layer").transition()
      .duration(2000)
        .attr("d", function(d) { return area(d.values); });

      test.exit().transition().duration(1500).style("opacity",0).remove();
```

Comment: This code segment looks exactly like the one in your question. Where's the difference?

Comment: It was the double svg element and some bad opacity setting. I still have questions about how to keep constancy with items nested in the layer data object.. Any chance we could take to chat?

Comment: Maybe this would be better as a separate question?