# How to update the data in a stacked area chart?

Tags: d3.js, stacked-area-chart

I've created a stacked area chart in d3.js and would like to update the chart with data from a CSV when one of the scenario buttons is clicked.

Here's a link to the bl.ocks.org gist I've created:   http://bl.ocks.org/saraquigley/094e38913b550cf5f27f

How do I correctly bind the data and get the chart to update and display the appropriate scenario.

Thanks!
Sara

Comment: This may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25954998/data-joins-with-d3-stack-layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your comment, [in code veritas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2573069/in-code-veritas). I was able to answer my own question by further cleaning up my code and dealing with a data filtering issue that I had caused. I've updated the gist, [same link as above](http://bl.ocks.org/saraquigley/094e38913b550cf5f27f) in case it helps anyone with a similar problem.

Sara